# Git checkout to a previous branch, do nothing, but why have something be staged?

Tags: git

I checkout to a existing branch, do nothing, and then want to check out to another existing branch. But it says:

```
xxx:~/OculusSDK/data$ git checkout AnotherExistingBranch
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    .DS_Store
    Samples/LibOVR_With_Samples.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/ken.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
    Samples/LibOVR_With_Samples.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/ken.xcuserdatad/xcdebugger/Breakpoints_v2.xcbkptlist
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

Then I do 'git status', it says:

```
    xxx:~/OculusSDK/data$ git status
    On branch master
    Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

    Changes not staged for commit:
      (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
      (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   ../.DS_Store
        modified:   ../Samples/LibOVR_With_Samples.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/ken.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
        modified:   ../Samples/LibOVR_With_Samples.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/ken.xcuserdatad/xcdebugger/Breakpoints_v2.xcbkptlist

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Why? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know that those were MacOS files. removing answer...

Comment: If you google "xcuserstate" and "ds_store git" there are a bunch of SO question about how to remove them from your repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that XCode was running at the same time. It will reload the files and write back to disk.

.DS_Store is a Mac OS file system info file, you will want to remove that, the other two are settings files from XCode.

Normally, just checking out from one branch and switching over to another will at most result into merges.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the branch you are checking out too has a different `.gitignore` which doesn't include those file types that you are now seeing in your status. Somewhere in the past, you added those files to your git repository. Then you added those filetypes to .gitignore but perhaps didn't remove those files from the repository. Git is then confused because it sees files which may have been committed in the past, removed/ignored via .gitignore but are now back because of your different .gitignore in this other branch.

To avoid this state, when I detect field which I should not have committed (and should be ignored), first I copy those files out to a new directory, then I remove them from Git (`git rm`), then I modify `.gitignore` to ignore those file types and commit that new `.gitignore`. Lastly, I move those files back into the original directory.